# How to install a package with pip

Tags: python, macos, pip

I am using Python 3.13 on macOS 14.2.1 (Sonoma), so far just to practice the language.

I need to add (install) a specialised library (openpyxl). Following the instructions in the library's documentation I use (in Terminal)

`pip install openpyxl`

As a response I get

`zsh: command not found: pip`

Can someone please tell me what is the (surely stupid) thing I am missing ?

Many thanks.

[image]

Comment: Have you added pip and python to your PATH? https://graycode.ie/blog/how-to-add-python-pip-to-path/

Comment: Are you aware that you are working with a preview release and the planned release date for Python 3.13 is in October this year?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found the answer. The correct command is :

`python3 -m pip install openpyxl`